# MASM615 and switching the address of two strings

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I am trying to write a MASM615 assembly program where part of the program switches the address of two strings if needed. However, I have no idea how to do this. Basically, I need to pass the two string pointers into a new procedure by reference, and the procedure switches the addresses.

Thus far I have:

```
lea eax, str1
lea ebx, str2
push ebx
push eax
call compare
```

So you see, the addresses are pushed into stack. In the procedure I pop them off of stack into the same registers (seems a little pointless, but oh well)... and then what? I feel like I need to somehow tell `str1` to point to the address in `ebx`, and `str2` to point to the address in `eax`, but how?!

Edit: Current test code....

```
TITLE MASM Template                        (main.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
str1 db "Hello",0
str2 db "Hi there",0

.data?
pStr1 dd ?
pStr2 dd ?

.code
main PROC
mov [pStr1],OFFSET str1
mov [pStr2],OFFSET str2

mov edx, [pStr1]
call WriteString
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: You can't change the address of a label. You can store its address in a variable (or a register) and then change the variable to contain some other address. Though it's not entirely clear what you need to swap the pointers _for_. If you just need to swap the pointers around temporarily you could simply pop them in the opposite order in which you pushed them (as in `push ebx push eax pop ebx pop eax`)

Comment: I need there to be two pointers to strings, and reverse them. so let us say we have: BYTE str1 "Hello!",0 and BYTE str2 "Hi there.",0.... if we do mov edx, OFFSET str1, call WriteString..... it should actually output "Hi there."  ...... if the strings need to somehow be pointers and not labels, as you say, then i guess that is fine.

Comment: (to attempt to be more clear, i get the feeling i need two new variables which will contain the addresses of the strings, and then instead of moving an offset into edx, i would do something like mov edx, stringAddress1.... is that right?

Comment: If I understand the question, you'll either need pointers to the string pointers and swap those, or you'll need to swap the *contents* of the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want something like this:

```
.data
str1 db "Hello",0
str2 db "Hi there",0

.data?
pStr dd ?

.code
mov [pStr],OFFSET str1
...
; if some condition is fulfilled, jump past this:
mov [pStr],OFFSET str2
...
mov edx,[pStr]
call WriteString
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but my experience is limited. I believe this might be the answer i'm looking for, but i need clarification please. it seems db is the same as BYTE, and dd for the pointer means its a double word, so DWORD? Thanks for your assistance, there is very little simple documentation that i can find around.

Comment: Yeah, db=declare byte, dw=declare word, dd=declare dword. MASM, TASM and NASM should all understand those (though the uninitialized form `dd ?` might have to be written as `resd 1` if you're using NASM).

Comment: This concept seems to work, however, the program seems to crash if i call WriteString. This shouldnt happen, since the string is 0 concatenated... i would post my test code, which is quite similar to yours, but this comment editor, unlike the editor i originally posted with, doesnt allow me to add new lines with the enter key. :\   EDIT: The string DOES print out, but crashes the program afterward.

Comment: Can't you edit your question instead and add your latest code? You might also want to specify which OS you're targetting (DOS expects strings to be terminated by a '$' character if you use its interrupt functions to print them, while Windows expecs a NUL (0) terminator).

Comment: such a simple fix, i have edited my original post. I am using windows, so it expects 0 terminated text.

Comment: You should add an `invoke ExitProcess,0` at the end of your main, in order to terminate your application properly.

Comment: DOH! Yes, i did forget to write "exit" as the last line in my main process. THANK YOU!